# Cats in SAS giving me blank space

Tags: sas

I'm trying to create a html line in SAS, as below.

```
   data _null_;
    exposurefilename1 = cats("\\fish\head\aram\Pricing\soup\fish_change", 2021, ".xlsx");
    file1 = cats('<a href =',exposurefilename1, '>', '"', exposurefilename1, '"', '</a>');
    call symput('file1', file1);
    run;
```

The output I expect would be:

<a href =\fish\head\arAm\Pricing\soup\fish_change2021.xlsx<"\fish\head\PAR\Pricing\soup\fish_change2021

However, it's giving me an extra line where it is
<a href=
\fish\head\aram\Pricing\soup\fish_change2021.xlsx<"\fish\head\PAR\Pricing\soup\fish_change2021

How would I fix this?

Comment: I don't get what is the problem. Is it because it is giving you `<a href=` instead of  `<a href =`? Shouldn't the final output be `<a href =\\fish\head\aram\Pricing\soup\fish_change2021.xlsx>"\\fish\head\aram\Pricing\soup\fish_change2021.xlsx"</a>` according to your code ?

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with your code as it is. It gives the expected output when I run it.